# How do I change the role name of a nodejs app services in application insights from "Web"?

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have two nodejs app services both connected to a single ApplicationInsights resource in Azure.

They both post events successfully, however when I click "Application Map" they are both shown under a single "Web" node, rather than two separate nodes.

My understanding is I must change the cloud role name, but I'm unsure of where to do that. Is it done in the node code, or can it somehow be done at the "App Service" level in Azure?

Answer (score 4):

This seemed to get me there:

```
const appInsights = require('applicationinsights')
const InsightsKey = process.env.APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
const insights = appInsights.setup(InsightsKey)
    
appInsights.defaultClient.context.tags[appInsights.defaultClient.context.keys.cloudRole] = 'Your New Role Name'

insights.start()
```

Comment: I am getting defaultClient undefined, am I missing anything?

Comment: The package name appears to still be valid. Double check that you ran `npm install`.

Comment: @NilayKothari Just call the `appInsights.setup()` first - it will initialise the `appInsights.defaultClient`, then you can reference it. (don't think it's still relevant though)